# CalendarView SelectedDates are not recorded in my _DateChanged method

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, calendar, calendarview

...but it is when i perform the action upon a button click.

This does not work:

XAML:

```
            <CalendarView CalendarViewDayItemChanging="MyCalendarView_DateChanged" x:Name="MyCalendarView" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" DisplayMode="Month" SelectionMode="Multiple" CalendarItemBackground="LightBlue" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

C#:

```
private void MyCalendarView_DateChanged(Object sender, object e)
    {
        SelectedDate.Text = "The selected date(s):" + "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i <= MyCalendarView.SelectedDates.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            SelectedDate.Text += MyCalendarView.SelectedDates[i].ToString() + "\n";
        }


    }
```

but this does work:

XAML:

```
            <Button x:Name="GoButton" Click="GoButton_Click" Content="Go!" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"   VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

C#:

```
private void GoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedDate.Text = "The selected date(s):" + "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i <= MyCalendarView.SelectedDates.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            SelectedDate.Text += MyCalendarView.SelectedDates[i].ToString() + "\n";
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with first method? Is the SelectedDates not supposed to be refreshed automatically?

I would prefer to avoid using button to record the user's dates' selection.

EDIT

And if in first method I use `RoutedEventArgs` instead of `Object` I get error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0123  No overload for 'MyCalendarView_DateChanged' matches delegate 'TypedEventHandler'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to monitor the Calendar View control `SelectedDates` collection dependency property, you should handle instead the `SelectedDatesChanged` event.

You've already correctly changed the `SelectionMode`property to `Multiple`, allowing multiple dates to be selected. In order to follow any update on the selected dates, you will provide your logic on the Event Handler for the `SelectedDatesChanged` event, rather than for the `CalendarViewDayItemChanging`, which is used to access an individual day item and for instance change some of its properties.

Comment: works like a charm. Thank You very much,. But could you redirect me to the microsoft documents where I could find SelectedDatesChanged and other properties of CalendarView? As I could not find anything helpful yeet...

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Here, you have access to the information regarding the CalendarView and all the events/properties exposed for it. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/calendar-view

Comment: Is it possible to cut the hour out of SelectedDate?